# Is there a way to edit button response twice or more in dpy?

Tags: discord, pycord, nextcord

I want to edit my button's response twice

This is what I've tried so far

```py
class HelloButtons(nextcord.ui.View):

    
    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Press me!", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def sayhi(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=discord.Embed(description='Updating...'), view=None)

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        await interaction.followup.edit_message(embed=self.embed, view=self)
```